# 8 people lined up to be photographed. In how many different ways can they line up if the shortest person is not next to the tallest person?

Tags: combinatorics

The way that I solved this question is by doing 8! - 2(7!) = 30240. Is there an alternate way to do this question? [image]

I tried doing it another way, using a circle. ( 6! . 5 . 8) = 28800. I am quite certain the first answer that I gave was correct, so I don't know what I did here was wrong.

Comment: I don't get your diagram. Why does it have two $5$'s and a t?

Comment: Of course, my bad! I completely forgot to explain. The numbers represent how many people can be in that spot. As the shortest person cannot be next to t, the tallest person, those numbers would be the case.

Comment: A slightly lengthier way is to use the gap method. You first have 6 persons in a line, Select two gaps out 7. (Ensures S and T are separated) Permute the 6 persons. and then permute the S and T between themselves

Comment: $8! - 2(7!)$ is the simplest way in my opinion.

Comment: @Aadi could you please further describe your method with calculations? I think it is quite intriguing to me.

Comment: @Woo Luke Added!

Comment: Am I mistaken or does something quite literally not add up?

Comment: Translating to a circle is not a good idea since in a circle every person has two neighbors, which is not true in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(A) Is the Answer Correct ?**
Yes , it is Correct.
We can put them in $8!$ ways , then remove the ways where the $2$ are next to each other , which is $2 \times 7!$.
$8!-2 \times 7! = 30240$

**(B) "Is there an alternate way to do this question?"**
Your Method is the most intuitive & the quickest.
I am giving this Alternative at your request.

(B1) Let the Shortest be at the Start. The Second Position can be $6$ of the others.
Then the rest (including the tallest) can be put $6!$ ways.
We have $6 \times 6!$
(B2) Likewise , when the Shortest is at the End.
We have $6 \times 6!$
(B3) Let the Shortest be somewhere in the Middle.
The other $6$ can be put in $6!$ ways.
The Shortest can be put in $5$ Positions in the Middle ($7$ Positions except the Start & the End)
The tallest can be put in $6$ ways ($8$ Positions except next to the Shortest)
We have $6 \times 5 \times 6!$

Hence (B1)+(B2)+(B3) gives $(6 \times 6!) + (6 \times 6!) + (6 \times 5 \times 6!) = 4320 + 4320 + 21600 = 30240$

This Alternative Method matches the Earlier Method , which gives Strength + Confirmation , though it is longer.

Comment: you were amazing :). tyvm

Answer (score 3):

Consider this set of people arranged on the basis of height $\{ P_1 ,P_2 ,P_3 ,P_4 ,P_5 ,P_6 ,P_7 ,P_8\}$

Lets line them up in any order first

$ \ P_2 \  \  P_3  \    \  P_4   \  \  P_5   \   \   P_6   \  \   P_7   \ $

Next let us add gaps between these people

$ |  \ P_2 \  |  \  P_3  \   |  \  P_4   \  |  \  P_5   \  |  \   P_6   \ |  \   P_7   \ |$

These gaps represent possible positions for $P_1 $ and $P_8$ . Hence we choose $2$ out of $7$ gaps and those gaps represent $P_1$ and $P_8$ 's position. this method helps us ensure that $P_1$ and $P_8$ are never together.

Selection of gaps:  $7\choose2$

Permutation of $P_1$ and $P_8$ within those chosen gaps:  $7\choose2$ $* 2$

Permutation of all $6$ persons :  $6!$

Final answer = $2 \times $$7\choose2$ $ \times 6!$ = $6 \times 7!$

Comment: this one is a very nice answer as well! I thank you both!

Comment: +1 , Nice Solution !!